# site not loading after enabling fastcgi in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi

I am developed one joomla site.It was working good.But site is not loading after enable the **FastCGI**.I don't understand what the problem is !

Simply it just shows some content only.What is problem ?

I have red some doc in [joomla doc](http://docs.joomla.org/How_does_FastCGI_affect_Joomla?) about this issue.But that not helping.

Any idea would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Please give us the following: Hosting environment? CGI version? Joomla Version? PHP version? any error logs? a link to the failing page? Anything that can help us debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I remember it being a bug... [this may help](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=22629)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to 
1.disable mod_rewrite in Jommla 1.5 administrator/global configuration/ page.
2.Use text-editor to change .htaccess file to be named htaccess.txt.
and that's it.
It works!